Spring-boot GraphQl output map to data issue
I've to map a graphql response in a data object. But in the end, the data is null.
String document = """
   query {
    entries(entry_ids: "12CA") {
        rcsb_id
        rcsb_accession_info {
            initial_release_date
        }
        audit_author {
            name
        }
        rcsb_primary_citation {
            pdbx_database_id_PubMed
            pdbx_database_id_DOI
        }
   }
   }""";
 
ClientGraphQlResponse response = graphQlClient.document("document").executeSync();
        System.out.println("response: " + response);
        ClientResponseField field = response.field("data");
        System.out.println("field: " + field);
        Data data  = field.toEntity(Data.class);
        System.out.println("data: " + data);

The output is:
response: {data={entries=[{rcsb_id=12CA, rcsb_accession_info={initial_release_date=1992-10-15T00:00:00Z}, audit_author=[{name=Nair, S.K.}, {name=Christianson, D.W.}], rcsb_primary_citation={pdbx_database_id_PubMed=1910042, pdbx_database_id_DOI=null}}]}}
field: org.springframework.graphql.client.DefaultClientResponseField@540b91dc
data: null
My data objects:

@lombok.Data
public class Data {
    public List<Entries> entries;
}
@Data
public class Entries {
 
    public String rcsb_id;
    public RcsbAccessionInfo  rcsb_accession_info;
    public List<AuditAuthor> audit_author;
    public RcsbPrimaryCitation rcsb_primary_citation;
}
@Data
public class RcsbAccessionInfo {
    public String initial_release_date;
}
@Data
public class AuditAuthor {
    public String name;
}
@Data
public class RcsbPrimaryCitation {
    public Integer pdbx_database_id_PubMed;
    public String pdbx_database_id_DOI;
}

Where am I wrong?

In the end, the solution is very simple.
Data data = response.toEntity(Data.class);


I think you need to get an object Entries.class or Entries[].class. The Data object appears to me to be an internal GraphQL object
Data data  = field.toEntity(Entries[].class);


I tried to change in Entries data = field.toEntity(Entries.class) but nothing changed. data is null

Check that you sent not null object. Give us a proof please

The proof is the output that I sent. The response of the server is: response: {data={entries=[{rcsb_id=12CA, rcsb_accession_info={initial_release_date=1992-10-15T00:00:00Z}, audit_author=[{name=Nair, S.K.}, {name=Christianson, D.W.}], rcsb_primary_citation={pdbx_database_id_PubMed=1910042, pdbx_database_id_DOI=null}}]}} and the field is org.springframework.graphql.client.DefaultClientResponseField@540b91dc

@EnricoMorelli Probably we don't understand each other. What you show is a response that your client got. It receives something sending by server. I asked what object sever sent. It can be found from server log, wireshark or some other independent  method. Your client might be wrong, so I don't trust it's output. Or might be right, in such case required object was not sent by server

The server response is a  JSon object. Using the server page where I can test the graphql query, the result is: { "data": {  "entries": [ { "rcsb_id": "12CA",         "rcsb_accession_info": {  "initial_release_date": "1992-10-15T00:00:00Z"         },  "audit_author": [ { "name": "Nair, S.K." },  { "name": "Christianson, D.W." }         ],  "rcsb_primary_citation": { "pdbx_database_id_PubMed": 1910042,           "pdbx_database_id_DOI": null  }}]}}
